# With iPadOS 17, can you lock the focus on an external USB camera?

Tags: autofocus, avcapturedevice, uvc

As of iPadOS 17, Apple's platform now allows us to make use of external USB video inputs by supporting the USB Video Device Class (UVC).  This is great, but...
Does anyone know how to specify "lock focus"?  There are many cases when my app wants to lock the focus on a camera to stop it from auto focusing as things pass in front of the camera.

Given an AVCaptureDevice, there is a method called "isFocusModeSupported" and I have tried it with all the external USB cameras I own and every mode returns NO.  (Even the AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus, which they clearly do support.)

I know that UVC does support locking focus.  Has anyone figured out a way to lock a camera's focus for use in iPadOS apps?

Swift or Objective-C, this question is more about whether the functionality exists.